# How long does Insertion Sort take to sort an array of 10 million elements?

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, insertion-sort, heapsort

My university teacher gave me an exercise to compare two sort methods, Insertion and Heap sort. I have to test four randomic integer arrays (with the length of 1000, 100k, 10 million and 1 billion elements) for both of the algorithms, and they have to be the same for both methods when sorting the specific array.

**Insertion Sort function**

```c
void insertSort(int len, int *arr)
{
    int contPrincipal;
    for (contPrincipal = 1; contPrincipal < len; contPrincipal++) {

        int aux = arr[contPrincipal], contSecondary;

        for (contSecondary = contPrincipal-1; contSecondary >= 0 && aux < arr[contSecondary]; contSecondary--) {
            arr[contSecondary+1] = arr[contSecondary];
        }

        arr[contSecondary+1] = aux;
    }
}
```

**Heap Sort functions**

```c
void heapSort(int len, int *heap) {
    heapConstruct(len, heap);
    int cont, aux;
    for (cont = len - 1; cont > 0; cont--) {
        aux = heap[0];
        heap[0] = heap[cont];
        heap[cont] = aux;
        heapDescend(0, cont, heap);
    }
}

void heapConstruct(int len, int *heap) {
    int cont;
    for (cont = (len / 2) - 1; cont >= 0; cont--) {
        heapDescend(cont, len, heap);
    }
}

void heapDescend(int pos, int len, int *heap) {
    int highestSon = (2 * pos) + 1;
    if (highestSon < len) {
        if (highestSon < len - 1) {
            if (heap[highestSon + 1] > heap[highestSon]) {
                highestSon = highestSon + 1;
            }
        }

        if (heap[pos] < heap[highestSon]) {
            int aux = heap[highestSon];
            heap[highestSon] = heap[pos];
            heap[pos] = aux;
            heapDescend(highestSon, len, heap);
        }
    }
}
```

**Main**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "functions.h"

int main(void) {
    long int len = 10;
    int cont;

    int *arrHeap = (int *)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    int *arrInsertion = (int *)malloc(len * sizeof(int));
    int *tmp;

    clock_t start;
    double diffheap, diffinsertion;

    printf("  Arr size   ,  HeapSort(s)  , InserionSort(s)\n");

    for (len = 1000; len <= 1000000000; len = len * 10 * 10) {
        tmp = (int *)realloc(arrHeap, len * sizeof(int));
        if (tmp == NULL && len > 1) {
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Overflow
        }
        arrHeap = tmp;

        tmp = (int *)realloc(arrInsertion, len * sizeof(int));
        if (tmp == NULL && len > 1) {
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  // Overflow
        }
        arrInsertion = tmp;

        for (cont = 0; cont < len; cont++) {
            arrHeap[cont] = rand();
        }

        for (cont = 0; cont < len; cont++) {
            arrInsertion[cont] = arrHeap[cont];
        }

        start = clock();
        insertSort(len, arrInsertion);
        diffinsertion = ((double)(clock() - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        start = clock();
        heapSort(len, arrHeap);
        diffheap = ((double)(clock() - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("%13li,%15f,%15f\n", len, diffheap, diffinsertion);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Seems like the insertion and heap sort code works, but I started it more than 3 hour ago, and now I don't know if it is running or not, because it stoped feedbacking me in the 10 million array sorting. Is it normal to take this long, or is something in my code wrong?

[Executing program in prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR2Nx.png)

Comment: For 10,000,000 elements, the first loop iterates through 9,999,999 elements. The second loop iterates through elements until it finds an earlier one that is not less than the first element. On average, that will be halfway through the earlier elements. So the number of iterations of the inner loop will be about the sum of the integers from 0 to 9,999,999 divided by two. That sum is about 10^7•10^7/4 = 10^14/4 = 25 trillion. You can stop the program now. Maybe it will finish the 10^7 case if you give it long enough, but it is not going to finish the 10^9 case.

Comment: If you begin with `100` and increase the array size 10-fold each time instead of 100-fold, you'll get a better projection of how long each one might take. Note that it quickly becomes evident that your `heapSort()` is *much* faster, but you omit an essential step: checking that the sorted arrays are the same.

Comment: Thanks! I will not even try the 1 billion elements array... But I'll leave the program sorting the 10 million elements for a while longer, just out of curiosity.

Comment: For future reference, if a program takes more than a minute, consider stopping it and adding a progress indicator. For example, In the outer loop of the insertion sort, put a printf like `if ((contPrincipal % 100000) == 0) printf("%d\n", contPrincipal);`

Comment: For the insertion sort my compilation went `100, 0.000000`, `1000, 0.001000`, `10000, 0.055000`, `100000, 5.701000`, `1000000, 558.443000` so the 10 mill is projected to take about 15 hours. The heap sort increased by about 15x for each 10x size, while the insertion sort increased by about 100x, so it gets increasingly worse than the heap sort with array size.

Comment: Wow... That's a lot of time. Thanks for showing it to me. Also, I do checked if the sorted arrays are the same, but only manually, that is, I tested some times with arrays with more or less 30 elements and get the same result, just viewing it at the prompt.